# screener for any candle close above previous day high and below prevoius day low

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i have code that only works when same script is opened but when i open different script it does not show the script name in lable which satisfied the condition as below code nazara and affle script opened it shows in buy condition but when i opened other 3 scripts then it does not show nazara and affle in lable.
can anybody solve this

```
//@version=5
indicator('PDH/PDL SCREENER', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

showscr = input(true, title='Show Screener Label')
posX_scr = input(20, title='Pos. Label x-axis')
posY_scr = input(1, title='Pos. Size Label y-axis')

t1 = input.symbol('NSE:ACE')
t2 = input.symbol('NSE:AEGISCHEM')
t3 = input.symbol('NSE:AFFLE')
t4 = input.symbol('NSE:AGI')
t5 = input.symbol('NSE:NAZARA')

High1 = request.security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', high\[1\], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
Low1 = request.security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', low\[1\], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(High1,color=color.orange , title="PDH")
plot(Low1,color=color.lime , title="PDL")

MAScanner() =\>

    buysignal = (low <= High1 and close > High1) or (low[1] <= High1 and close[1] > High1)
    sellsignal = (high >= Low1 and close < Low1) or (high[1] >= Low1 and close[1] < Low1)
    [buysignal, sellsignal]

\[t01, s01\] = request.security(t1, timeframe.period, MAScanner())
\[t02, s02\] = request.security(t2, timeframe.period, MAScanner())
\[t03, s03\] = request.security(t3, timeframe.period, MAScanner())
\[t04, s04\] = request.security(t4, timeframe.period, MAScanner())
\[t05, s05\] = request.security(t5, timeframe.period, MAScanner())

pot_label = 'BUY:- \\n'
pot_label := t01 ? pot_label + t1 + '\\n' : pot_label
pot_label := t02 ? pot_label + t2 + '\\n' : pot_label
pot_label := t03 ? pot_label + t3 + '\\n' : pot_label
pot_label := t04 ? pot_label + t4 + '\\n' : pot_label
pot_label := t05 ? pot_label + t5 + '\\n' : pot_label

scr_label = 'SELL:- \\n'
scr_label := s01 ? scr_label + t1 + '\\n' : scr_label
scr_label := s02 ? scr_label + t2 + '\\n' : scr_label
scr_label := s03 ? scr_label + t3 + '\\n' : scr_label
scr_label := s04 ? scr_label + t4 + '\\n' : scr_label
scr_label := s05 ? scr_label + t5 + '\\n' : scr_label

f_colorscr(\_valscr) =\>
\_valscr ? #00000000 : na

f_printscr(\_txtscr) =\>
var \_lblscr = label(na)
label.delete(\_lblscr)
\_lblscr := label.new(time + (time - time\[1\]) \* posX_scr, ohlc4\[posY_scr\], \_txtscr, xloc.bar_time, yloc.price, f_colorscr(showscr), textcolor=showscr ? color.yellow : na, size=size.large , style=label.style_label_lower_left)
\_lblscr
f_printscr(pot_label + '\\n' + scr_label)
```

Comment: Can you be more precise and more explicite, as is, it is hard to understand your problem.

Comment: when you apply this indicator we get lable of buy and sell if screener condition satisfied then script name will come under either buy or sell lable but currently even if condition satisfy its not showing under any lable. then if i open the same script which satisfying condition of pdh,pdl break its showing, i want to see the scripts (which satisfying condition) under the lables even if i open any random scripts so i can check name and go to that script